# How to find the tag Value in the dynamic JSON-Object with Java 8

Tags: java, json, java-8, java-stream, jsonparser

I have *JSON-object* which has a *dynamic key* inside it. I need to get a specific *value* mapped to this dynamic Key.

***For example:*** value `"10.00"` will be returned for the key `"value"` and value `REFUND_COMPLETED` will be obtained as a result for the key `"refundState"`

***Code:***

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json2 = "{\n"
                + "    \"refundStatusDetails\": {\n"
                + "        \"txn_f2a7802c-ef84-43c3-8615-5f706b995c23\": {\n"
                + "            \"refundTransactionId\": \"txn_f2a7802c-ef84-43c3-8615-5f706b995c23\",\n"
                + "            \"requestId\": \"refund-request-id-1\",\n"
                + "            \"refundState\": \"REFUND_COMPLETED\",\n"
                + "            \"amount\": {\n"
                + "                \"currency\": \"INR\",\n"
                + "                \"value\": \"10.00\"\n"
                + "            },\n"
                + "            \"refundRequestedTime\": 1513788119505,\n"
                + "}";

        System.out.println("JSON: " + json2);
        JsonParser p = new JsonParser();
        Map<String,String> res =check("refundState", p.parse(json2));
        System.out.println("JSON: " + res.get("refundState"));
    }

    private static Map<String,String> check(String key, JsonElement jsonElement) {
        Map<String,String> res = new HashMap<>();
        if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
            Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().entrySet();
            entrySet.stream().forEach((x) ->{
                if (x.getKey().equals(key)) {
                    res.put(x.getKey(),x.getValue().toString());
                }
            });
        }
        return res;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have JSON Object which has a **dynamic key** inside the object I need a
> specific key **value**

The recursive method listed below is capable of fetching the *value* mapped to the provided *key* from a ***nested*** JSON-object.

The method return an optional result.

If provided `JsonElement` is not a `JsonObject` an *empty optional* will be returned.

Otherwise, if the given JSON-object contains the *given key* the corresponding *value* wrapped by an optional will be returned. Or if it's not the case the entry set obtained from an object will be processed with stream. And for every JSON-object in the stream method `getValue()` will be called recursively.

If the given key is present in one of the nested objects, the first encountered non-empty optional will be returned. Or empty optional if the key was not found.

```
private static Optional<JsonElement> getValue(String key, JsonElement jsonElement) {
    if (!jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    JsonObject source = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

    return source.has(key) ? Optional.of(source.get(key)) :
            source.entrySet().stream()
                    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                    .filter(JsonElement::isJsonObject)
                    .map(element -> getValue(key, element))
                    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(Optional.empty());
}
```

`main()` - demo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json2 =
            """
                      {
                      "refundStatusDetails": {
                        "txn_f2a7802c-ef84-43c3-8615-5f706b995c23": {
                          "refundTransactionId": "txn_f2a7802c-ef84-43c3-8615-5f706b995c23",
                          "requestId": "refund-request-id-1",
                          "refundState": "REFUND_COMPLETED",
                          "amount": {
                            "currency": "INR",
                            "value": "10.00"
                          },
                          "refundRequestedTime": "1513788119505"
                        }
                      }
                    }""";

    JsonElement element = JsonParser.parseString(json2);
    System.out.println(getValue("refundState", element));
    System.out.println(getValue("value", element));
}
```

**Output**

```
Optional["REFUND_COMPLETED"]
Optional["10.00"]
```

*Note:*

- If you are using **Java 17** you can utilize text blocks by plasing the text between the triple quotation marks `""" JSON """`.
- Constructor of the `JsonParser` is *deprecated*. Instead of instantiating this class, we have to use its *static methods*.

Comment: getvalue() method only searching for outer object key like if my key is "refundStatusDetails" it return value  Optional<String> res =getValue("refundStatusDetails", p.parse(json2));
        System.out.println("res: " + res.isPresent());  **  res: true **   but if i am searching for inner ke it return false            eg:   Optional<String> res =getValue("refundState", p.parse(json2));
        System.out.println("res: " + res.isPresent());    ** res: false **

Comment: @jsp So the *given key* could be contained **either** in *outer JSON-object* or in the *nested JSON-object*. I'm getting it right now? And method should be able to handle both cases?

Comment: @jsp And one more question that needs to be clarified: how deeply these objects could be nested? I mean cases like that: `{ "outer" : { "inner1" : { "inner2" : { "targetKey" : targetValue" } } }`, object inside another object, inside another object...

Comment: above case could be possible in my case it is nested 3 deeper object {
  "outer": {
    "inner1": {"targetKey2": targetValue2",
      "inner2": {
        "targetKey": targetValue" } } }

Comment: @jsp I've updated the answer. Provided solution is able to process a **nested** JSON-object of an arbitrary depth. I've used an example from the question with keys `"refundState"` and `"value"` as a demo. So that now it's a *complete runnable code*. Please, try it out and tell whether it matches your requirements or something needs to be improved?

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested to access any field in a JSON object structure then you can use a method like the following one that I used to access the fields that I needed from an JSON Array structure using "package org.json;"

```
public static final String COLLECTION_OBJECT = "collectionObject";
public static final String FIELD = "field";

private ArrayList<Object> getSearchFilterCriteriaAsString() {

    String jsonString = "{" +
                            "\n\"collectionObject\": " +
                                "[\n" +
                                    "{" +
                                        "\n\"field\": \"productId\"," +
                                        "\n\"value\": \"3\"," +
                                        "\n\"operator\": \"EQUALS\"\n" +
                                    "},\n" +
                                    "{" +
                                        "\n\"field\": \"productPrice\"," +
                                        "\n\"value\": \"15\"," +
                                        "\n\"operator\": \"MORE_THAN\"\n" +
                                    "},\n" +
                                    "{" +
                                        "\n\"field\": \"productQuantity\"," +
                                        "\n\"value\": \"25\"," +
                                        "\n\"operator\": \"LESS_THAN\"\n" +
                                    "}\n" +
                                "]\n" +
                            "}";
                            
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(COLLECTION_OBJECT);

        ArrayList<Object> filteredObjectsList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (jsonArray != null) {

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject filteredObj = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);

                filteredObjectsList.add(filteredObj.getString(FIELD));
            }
            
        }
        
        return filteredObjectsList;
    }
```

As long as you know your key values you can parse any JSON as deep you want, without to care about how big it is, how many attributes it has.